# GNUmakfile with the same output but different dependancy

Tags: gnu-make

Not sure how we can achieve this, I have two rules with the same output def.out but it depends on two different files (NOT at the same time), one is abc.xml and the other one is def.xml . In the makefile, when I call def.out, how does it know to call the first rule or the 2nd rule? Again, this def.out doesn't depend on abc.xml and def.xml at the same time.

def.out : abc.xml
    ......

def.out : def.xml
    ......

Comment: First you have to define to yourself (and to us) how you know which dependency should be used to create def.out.  You can't get make to do it unless you know how to do it first.  Then we can try to help.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is don't have two of the same target.

def_abc.out:

and

def_def.out:

... because you DO have to tell the make utility which rule you want to use, don't you?  Or if you think the system is going to be able to figure it out on its own, then use the one target, but 'effectively two actions'.

def.out :   
      (action that tests what times this is)
            (if it is "abc.xml time")
                make def_abc.out
            (else)
                make def_def.out

You can add in code as you see fit to rename objects at the right time.

But you asked "how does it know to call the first rule or the 2nd rule?"
and my answer is "you either tell it when you call it, or tell it how to know when you code up the makefile".